# Redimensionar Array Multidimensional/Associativo a partir de um ResultSet

Tags: array, asp, array-multidimensional, array-associativo

Estou tentando alimentar um *array* multidimensional e associativo a partir de um ResultSet, porém acusa o seguinte erro:

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'
Expected end of statement
/beta/comercialBannersRelatorioGerado.asp, line 53
Redim preserve arrayRs("porIP", "mesPorIP") = rsRelatorio1("mesPorIP")
--------------------------------------------^
```

E aqui o código onde tento fazer isso:

```
Dim arrayRs() 
while not rsRelatorio1.EOF
    Redim preserve arrayRs("porIP", "mesPorIP") = rsRelatorio1("mesPorIP")
    Redim preserve arrayRs("porIP", "viewsPorIP") = rsRelatorio1("viewsPorIP")
    Redim preserve arrayRs("porIP", "clickPorIP") = rsRelatorio1("clickPorIP")
rsRelatorio1.movenext
wend
```

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%C3%ADtulo/1911#1911

Comment: Alterado, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O comando `Redim` não permite a atribuição de valor inicial.

A mensagem `Expected end of statement` informada no erro se refere que era esperado o fim da declaração no comando `Redim` após o ")".